# About the commutativity of the algebra $L^1 (G)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, convolution, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

I would like to know, under what condition on the group $G$ (abelian, compact or localement compact ...), the algebra $L^1 (G)$ is commutative?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a locally compact group $G$, the convolution algebra $L^1(G)$ is commutative if and only if G is Abelian.

This is Theorem 1.6.4 in *Principles of Harmonic Analysis* by Deitmar and Echterhoff.

Comment: I suspect the proof passes through bounded approximate identities. Is that correct?

Comment: @CameronWilliams. No, in fact it does not. It should be easy to check the reference, otherwise I can insert the proof later.